# É possível retratar uma sugestão de edição?

Tags: suporte, edições-sugeridas

Sugeri uma edição [em uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/292025/78713) incluindo algumas informações. Somente depois atentei para o fato de que a minha sugestão meio que mudaria significantemente o seu conteúdo, e na verdade merecia uma nova resposta ao invés da edição.

Então fiquei com algumas dúvidas:

- É possivel retratar uma sugestão de edição minha (caso ainda não tenha sido revisada)?
- Tem como confirmar que a minha revisão foi rejeitada*?

**Cliquei em editar novamente e o conteúdo sugerido por mim não estava lá, presumi que isso fosse um **sinal** da rejeição*

Comment: Sua edição: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/163385 - Eu e um outro revisor a rejeitamos exatamente por estar alterando significativamente a intenção do autor da resposta original, tal como você se atentou depois.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Isso! Eu queria ter a confirmação, mas acabo de ver que [a rejeição/sugestão fica registrada na aba `atividade` do meu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/78713/diego-rafael-souza?tab=activity). Obrigado mais uma vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver se a Edição foi rejeitada vai no seu `perfil > participação > atividades > sugestão`

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/78713/diego-rafael-souza?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para **Reverter** uma edição que vc fez, vai na *pergunta* que vc editou e entra na `edição > reverter`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vc retira a edição e ela volta do jeito que estava anteriormente. *(vc inclusive pode reverter edições de outras pessoas)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Eu pretendia poupar os revisores do trabalho caso eu perceba que fiz caca antes de a fila andar, mas ser um pouco mais crítico também resolve =). (Aliás acabei de perceber que tenho um monte de sugestão de edição formatando o código fonte que parece ser irrelevante -.-')

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza É bom acompanhar pra ver a onde a gente está errando, eu tb já foi rejeitado algumas vezes, hj edito com mais critério, **e nunca coloco ou retiro uma virgula que seja do código do autor**

Comment: Sim, vou tentar melhorar, achei que estivesse sendo útil. Particularmente eu nem leio questão com código não identado / com identação bizarra, edito antes e depois leio. Mas aparentemente não é um requisito de legibilidade comum. Bobagem, esse é fácil de resolver. As outras 'rejeições' são por conflito com outra edição existente (_timing_)